# Sorting an NSArray by a formula using object properties

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray

I've seen plenty of questions on here about sorting `NSArray`'s, especially ones full of custom objects, but it always seems to come down to a specific property or value that people are sorting by.  Sorting by name, sorting by age, sorting by date, etc.

But is it possible to sort an `NSArray` by a formula using the objects' properties, rather than just by a single property alone?  For example, if I have a custom class...

```
@interface SYSprocket : NSObject

@property int numberOfDoodads;
@property int widthOfWidgets;
```

and an input variable `(int)extraNumber`, is it possible to sort an `NSArray` of `SYSprocket`'s by the formula `(numberOfDoodads / widthOfWidgets) + extraNumber`?

My arrays aren't that big, so I could just iterate through them if needed, but this seems like the kind of thing that shouldn't be impossible, right?  Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort using custom logic, you could use `- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr` method on `NSArray` which takes a block with sorting logic and returns a sorted array.

#### Example:

```
sortedArray = [arrayWithObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    
    // cast obj1, obj2 to appropriate classes
    // use if/else to do the comparision
    // return NSOrderedSame / NSOrderedAscending / NSOrderedDescending

}];
```